# Show compilation errors with async export in org-mode?

Tags: org-export

When exporting to PDF via LaTeX, compilation errors are shown in a buffer *Org PDF LaTeX output*, which is fine but can be time-consuming.

Using async export is faster but I do know how to show the compilation errors. The documentation only talks about an "export stack" (C-u C-u and C-c C-e), which only shows a list of process like :

```
# Backend Age  Source
1 latex   0:05 /home/john/test.tex
```

I would like

- to know if the compilation is successful
- otherwise, to show the error log

Thanks !